How to tell an anxious person they are being anxious? How to tell an angry person to calm down?
This is a pretty pure question: I don't know if the traditional sources even deals with this, but I suspect they might, and hope they do given how nogeah it is to maintaining goodness in our interpersonal relationships. There are probably very good aggada and midrashim that help with this, and rishonim, mussar and chassidus that deal with this in some useful way.


Try telling an anxious person that they are being too anxious about something. Experience says that this isn't something that works, and can lead to strife, ch'v. Same as with telling someone angry to calm down - that seems to infuriate them even more, ch'v. I hope I don't have to justify this with some source.

My question is - if we do actually want to convey to someone that they are indeed being overly worried, and they don't need to, or we need to get through to someone that it's really important, and in their own interest (as well as everyone elses) to calm down as quickly as possible, how should we go about it?

I want a traditionally sourced idea (there is plenty of decent secular advice). I don't mind if this is one's own chiddush, so long as it is based on sources (and hence shiurim by contemporary Rabbis and "radio Rabbis" are also welcome if relevant).

רַבִּי שִׁמְעוֹן בֶּן אֶלְעָזָר אוֹמֵר, אַל תְּרַצֶּה אֶת חֲבֵרְךָ בִשְׁעַת כַּעֲסוֹ, וְאַל תְּנַחֲמֶנּוּ בְּשָׁעָה שֶׁמֵּתוֹ מֻטָּל לְפָנָיו, וְאַל תִּשְׁאַל לוֹ בִשְׁעַת נִדְרוֹ, וְאַל תִּשְׁתַּדֵּל לִרְאוֹתוֹ בִשְׁעַת קַלְקָלָתוֹ:
Rabbi Shimon ben Elazar said: Do not try to appease your friend during his hour of anger; Nor comfort him at the hour while his dead still lies before him; Nor question him at the hour of his vow; Nor strive to see him in the hour of his disgrace. Avot 4:18

This is such a good eitzah that I can’t imagine any Rabbi arguing against it. Psychologists wouldn’t either, it seems. One reason for this is that we don’t know all the reasons for the person’s anxiety or situation. We may not know enough to tell them that their emotional response is wrong.

The problem is that anger and anxiety can, unfortunately, occur even if a person knows in his mind that his emotions are irrational; especially, but not exclusively, in the case of a genuine emotional condition

@Shimshon Imagine we see someone we deeply love, who is inexperienced, arguing with a police officer. The police officer is being very pateint, yet we know that the person is unaware that this police officer has already had plenty of reason to arrest this person. Then it is very practical - right now this person needs to calm down, and they don't realise and only you do, and you deeply love them. Is this Mishna saying, tough, we have to just resign to the fact that their whole life is about to get ruined, we are not allowed to try to appease them? If it's more complicated, this question stands

@Qwertrl In my mind, that just makes this question more challenging, certainly not impossible to answer. Can you suggest an edit I can make to this question?

@RabbiKaii L’choira that would be an exceptional case where pikuach nefesh and dina d’malchusa dina would override this mishnah.

@Shimshon so what is the halacha and what are the principles behind it. Any practical advice drawable from that process? That would be an excellent approach to answering this Q

@RabbiKaii Berakhot 7a From where is it derived that one must not placate a person while he is in the throes of his anger, rather he should mollify him after he has calmed down? As it is written, when following the sin of the Golden Calf, Moses requested that the Divine Presence rest upon Israel as it had previously, God said to him: “My face will go, and I will give you rest” (Exodus 33:14). Rabbi Yoḥanan explained: The Holy One, Blessed be He, said to Moses: Wait until My face of wrath will pass and I will grant your request. One must wait for a person’s anger to pass as well.

Yad HaChazakah Human Dispositions 5:7 He should not try to placate a man in the moment of his anger.

On futher reflection, it’s one thing to console an anxious person, and that may even be a mitzvah. But one should avoid trying to give mussar or tochacha to an angry person. Chazal liken anger to avodah zarah. According to R’ Laibl Wolf it is possible to completely eliminate anger.
